# A manifold admits top form iff orientable.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, orientation

I'm trying to prove the following statement, and I think I'm nearly there but I can't seem to figure out the last step. Any tips/feedback/hints would be greatly appreciated.

> A smooth $n$-manifold $M$ admits an orientation if and only if $M$ has a nowhere vanishing $n$-form.

Let $\omega$ be such a form. In a chart $(U,\varphi)$, there is a map $f:\varphi_\alpha(U)\to\mathbb{R}$ so that $\omega = f d x^1_\alpha\wedge\dots \wedge d x^n_\alpha$. In particular $f=\omega(\partial_1^\alpha,\dots, \partial_n^\alpha)$. Now choose a chart so that $f(x)>0$, and let $(U,\varphi_\alpha)$ be another such chart with $g:\varphi_\beta(U_\beta)\to\mathbb{R}$ that has $\omega = g d x^1_\beta\wedge\dots d x^n_\beta$ and $g(x)>0$. Now,
\begin{equation}
    g = \omega(\partial_1^\beta,\dots, \partial_n^\beta) = \omega (D_1 (\varphi_\alpha\circ\varphi_\beta^{-1})_1^j\partial_j^\beta,\dots, D_n (\varphi_\alpha\circ\varphi_\beta^{-1})_n^j\partial_j^\alpha)
\end{equation}
But this is just $\det(D \varphi_\alpha\circ\varphi_\alpha^{-1})f$. Building an atlas this way gives an orientation. Now suppose we have an oriented atlas $\{(U_\alpha,\varphi_\alpha)\}$, and write, in each chart $\omega_\alpha = d x^1_\alpha\wedge\dots\wedge d x^n_\alpha$, and choose a partition of unity $\{\rho_\alpha\}$ subbordinate to $\{(U_\alpha,\varphi)\}$. Define $\omega =\sum_\alpha \omega_\alpha \rho_\alpha$. Fix $p\in M$. For open $U\subset M$ with $p\in U$, we know $\sum_\alpha \rho_\alpha \omega_\alpha$ is a finite sum $\sum_{i=1}^k \rho_i \omega_i$. Then, around $p\in U_i$
\begin{equation}
    \omega(\partial^i_1,\dots,\partial_n^i) = \sum_{i=1}^k \rho_i \omega_i (\partial^i_1,\dots,\partial_n^i) 
\end{equation}

Comment: Perhaps you could tell us your definition of "admits an orientation". (There are many; one of these is "has a nowhere-vanishing $n$-form", in which case your claim is a tautology, so I assume yours is not *that* one!)

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that, my definition is orientable if determinate of the Jacobian of each transition map is positive.

Comment: So why have you not finished the final sentence?

Comment: I'm not sure how to finish it. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: So what tells you that $\omega(p)>0$? You have it all set up correctly.

Comment: That $\omega_i (\partial^i_1,\dots,\partial_n^i)$ should be the determinate of something but  I'm struggling with exactly what it is (lost in the indices). Then it'd follow from $\rho_i>0$. Sorry for the late reply!

Comment: It's just the fact that the orientations of the different charts are all compatible.

Comment: What exactly should I write though? The notation is kind of confusing me. What is $dx^1_i\wedge \dots dx^n_i(\partial_1^i,\dots,\partial_n^i)$ actually equal too. Sorry thank you this is probably a stupid question.